# How to use loopback with nuxt js?

Tags: rest, vue.js, loopbackjs, nuxt.js

Loopback (API server) is on port 3000
Nuxt JS (Client server) is on port 5000

I tried to build nuxt js to SPA/Prerendered pages and move it to Loopback client folder, but since I use auth middleware in nuxt js, the functionality gets broken.

What's the good way to integrate those two?
How to deploy the server and the client for production mode?

Comment: https://github.com/yassipad/nuxt-loopback

Answer (score 0):

you can do it yourself as follows:

1. Install Loopback globaly `npm install -g loopback-cli` and run loopback creator in terminal `lb`
2. Go to project folder from creator and install nuxt `npm i -S nuxt`
3. create nuxt.config.js with set [srcDir](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-srcdir/)
4. change loopback port in /server/config.json on 8080
5. To run api with app toghether install concurrently devDependencie and edit package.json `"start": "concurrently \"nuxt\" \"node .\"",`

Your nuxt app should be run on port 3000 and loopback on 8080.